# Can we set Custom email address with out email forwarding for inbound emails?

Tags: apex-email-service, send-email, email2case, inboundservices

I want to send and receive emails and associate these email messages to custom object records.
**For Sending of emails** - I wanted to use Send Email Action.
**For receiving of emails** - I wanted to write a inbound email services to capture the email and associate the emailmessage to existing custom object record based on predefined unique value in email subject.

The challenge here is for receiving email, I configured email service which created long email id.  I want short custom email id to be configured.
**is there a way that I can use short email id with out using email forwarding feature Or Is there a way custom Thread Id can help here??**

Comment: `is there a way that I can use short email id with out using email forwarding feature` - I don't think so - SFDC binds the long email address to your inbound email service. Why can't you set up email forwarding in your company's email server?

Comment: @cropredy: We have more than 50+ group email ids. All of them has to be configured for forwarding which is a huge pain every time a new emailId has to be configured.